_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks not working in c, visual studio 2022
I'm using Visual Studio 2022.
For some reason ? _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks(); is not showing any leaks, only exit with 0.
Even though I did malloc char* leakyMemory for a test, but didn't help anyways.
Everything is working fine, I just want to check the memory leak.
#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
#include <crtdbg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h> // For Sleep()
// Include your store header file
#include "Store.h"
#include "Customer.h"
#define TEXT_FILE "store2.txt"
#define BIN_FILE "store.bin"

int main() {

    _CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF);
    Store myStore;
    
    char* leakyMemory = (char*)malloc(128);
    leakyMemory = "ssssss";
   
    int roleChoice = 0, actionChoice = 0;;

    //// Initialize the store
    if (!initStoreFromFiles(&myStore)) {
        printf("Failed to initialize the store.\n");
        //exit(0);
    }
   /*initStore(&myStore);*/
    do {
        printf("\nAre you a customer or an employee?\n");
        printf("1. Customer\n");
        printf("2. Employee\n");
        printf("3. Developer Menu(to see all options)\n");
        printf("0. Exit and save\n");
        scanf("%d", &roleChoice);

        switch (roleChoice) {
        case 1: // Customer
            showCustomerMenu(&myStore);
            break;

        case 2: // Employee
            showEmployeeMenu(&myStore);
            break;
        case 3: // Developer 
            showDeveloperMenu(&myStore);
            break;

        case 0: // Exit
            
            printf("Exiting...\n");
            saveStoreToFile(&myStore, TEXT_FILE);
            saveStoreToBinFile(&myStore, BIN_FILE);
            
            
            break;

        default:
            printf("Invalid role. Please try again.\n");
        }
    } while (roleChoice != 0);

    freeStore(&myStore);
    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
    
    return 0;
   
}


Welcome to StackOverflow. Please post a [mre]. We cannot test your code because we don't have "Store.h", "Customer.h", don't know what initStoreFromFiles is etc. You should be able to create a minimal version demonstrating the leak detection issue.

If it compiles (MS VC does), leakyMemory = "ssssss"; overwrites the pointer just obtained by malloc();. Use strcpy() to copy a string.

@WeatherVane I think the OP did this on purpose to get a memory leak.

You get to control where the debug output is reported using _CrtSetReportMode() (and _CrtSetReportFile()). You'll find an example that redirects to STDERR here.

You want this:
#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <crtdbg.h>

int main()
{
  _CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF);
  char *leak = malloc(199);
  strcpy(leak, "Hello world!");
  leak = "$$$$";
  return 0;
}

In the Output Tab in Visual Studio (and not in the console Window) you'll see something like this:
Detected memory leaks!
Dumping objects ->
C:\Users\Test\source\ConsoleApplication2\file2.c(11) : {81} normal block at 0x0000017F75AC07E0, 199 bytes long.
 Data: <Hello world!    > 48 65 6C 6C 6F 20 77 6F 72 6C 64 21 00 CD CD CD 
Object dump complete.
The program '[0xBFAC] ConsoleApplication2.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).



Confirmed that I got the memory leak report in the output pane. +1.

Perhaps the OS never performs the actual allocation since the memory isn't used anywhere? And the dynamic analyzer only looks at actually allocated memory?

@Lundin that doesn't seem the case at least in debug builds with Visual Studio. Removing the strcpy doesn't change the behaviour of the leak detector.

@Lundin The OS cannot determine whether the memory of an allocation request is ever used, and the compiler cannot optimize out the call to malloc() either, as it has side effects.

@IInspectable Of course it can, why would the OS not be able to tell if a certain area of memory is written to? That's nonsense. And compilers optimize out malloc calls all the time, as for example the latest gcc -O3 does with this very code. https://godbolt.org/z/chMne7M9f

@Lundin The OS can easily track memory accesses, but that requires that the memory is set aside already. This question is specifically about MSVC and MSVC cannot optimize out a call to malloc() due to observable side effects. This Q&A literally revolves around one such side effect of calling malloc().
